# model loading error due to version conflict R

Tags: r, h2o

I updated my h2o to the newest version and then tried to load the pre-trained model by typing:

```
randomforest = h2o.loadModel('randomforest')
```

However, it shows:

```
 Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
 ERROR MESSAGE:
 Found version 3.10.5.3, but running version 3.14.0.7
```

Does that mean I need to retrained all the model I built before ? That's extremely inconvenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will need to re-train the models using the same version of H2O (the version you train a model needs to be the same as the version you load the model with). H2O binary models are not compatible across major versions.

For binary models, this is the standard practice -- you will have the same situation if you use scikit-learn, for example.

If you want to use MOJO/POJO models in production, those are not tied to a particular version of H2O since they are just plain Java code and do not require the H2O cluster to be running.

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems like I have to retrain it.

Comment: Lauren, you wrote "3.14.*". Does that mean a model built in any 3.14.x.x can now be loaded in any other 3.14.x.x ? I thought it had to be an exact match, right down to the minor version. E.g. a model built in 3.14.0.6 or 3.14.0.8 won't run in 3.14.0.7?  If this has changed it is a small step in the right direction!

Comment: yes it has to be an exact match let me update that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reinstall the old version. In anaconda, for example,

```
conda install -c h2oai h2o=3.14.0.7
```

Worked for me!